Counterexample to $(n\in\mathbb{Z}\implies f(n)=g(n))\implies (n\in\mathbb{Z}\implies f'(n)=g'(n))$
I came up with the following conjecture. Let $f,g$ be functions differentiable on $\mathbb{R}.$ If for every integer $n,$ we have $f(n)=g(n),$ then for every integer $n,$ we also have $f'(n)=g'(n).$ After thinking about it, I think it's not true. However, I'm having trouble finding a counterexample.
Does there exist functions $f,g$ that are differentiable on the real line, and
$n\in\mathbb{Z}\implies f(n)=g(n),$ but there exists an $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $f'(m)\neq g'(m)?$

$f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ and $g(x)=-\sin(\pi x)$ both verify that $f(n)=0=g(n)$ for every integer $n$.
Nonetheless, $$f'(n)=\pi(-1)^n\neq \pi(-1)^{n+1}=g'(n)$$
so their derivatives are different at every integer.

You can't predict anything about the derivatives of a function from its values at a set of points isolated from one another.(*) You don't need formulas to see this.
Imagine the points on the graph above the isolated points you care about. Now take your pencil and draw a nice smooth curve through them from left to right. Clearly you can arrange any slope you like at those points.
(*)That statement read literally is false. If $a < b$ and $f(a) < f(b)$ then $f$ has a positive derivative somewhere between $a$ and $b$. But you can't say anything about the derivatives at $a$ or $b$.

Hint: consider the zero function and another function that you know that is periodically equal to zero.

I can't think of such a function that once extended is continuous.

@Hilbert Don't think about the problem on $\mathbb{Z}$. Think about it on $\mathbb{R}$ and then restrict to $\mathbb{Z}$. My hint of periodically was a very strong hint toward a solution!
